# Macro, erase data in a row (with locked cells in mixed positions)

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a multi use spreadsheet at work. In one of the spreadsheets I am trying to find a way to be able to add a button which would clear some cell values based on currently active cell (current selection?).

Spreadsheet layout:
| E7 data "U"nlocked | F7 data "U" | G7 auto calculation ("L"ocked) | H7:L7 mixed content (values and data validation list) | M7:O7 auto calc "L" | two more mixed columns...

I am trying to add some kind of button which would:
When E7 is selected will only clear editable cells: E7,F7,H7,I7,J7,K7,L7,P7,R7.

This would make my life easier as I need to keep file protected/locked...as you can imagine clearing whole row will not work...

I am currently using similar solution in another spreadshit:
Range("AN3", "AN15").Value = 0 '.Value = "" is also working.
I'm just not sure how to bite current selection and only certain cells next to it :/

Thank you so much for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Cleardata()
Set ma = ActiveCell.MergeArea
On Error GoTo errHand
If ma = ActiveCell Then
If MsgBox("FORMAT C:/ ?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, Range("E:F,H:L,P:P,R:R")).ClearContents
GoTo final
errHand:
MsgBox "WOW! You are not Trump...you can't grab 'em merged cells..."
Exit Sub
final:
On Error GoTo 0
'End With
End If
End Sub
```

This would be my full solution cause I have some other data in that same sheet and this way It will prevent showing confusing Debug messages for my colleagues if they'll click by mistake in the wrong place or they'll assume Excel can do that very much for them xD
Thank you once again!